# Adding web part to page in Modern view

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-pages

(Apologies if I am not using the exact English terms; I'm using SharePoint in French.)

I'm using SharePoint online. When I edit the home page of the site, a ribbon appears giving me many possibilities, including adding web parts and applications, and setting the layout. This would allow me, for example, to add a given view of a list to that page.

Currently, if I create another Page, it is displayed in the new (Modern) view. If I try to edit it, no ribbon appears and I'm limited to added about a dozen  things, which do not include the possibility of adding a view of an existing list, or any existing webpart. Furthermore, I cannot change the layout of the page, by having multiple columns.

Unlike other "pages" of the site, there is no link on a created Page which allows me to switch to a classical view.

How can I either switch a Page to the classical view and have access to the ribbon when editing OR, at the very least, how can I add existing lists on that page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A modern page does not allow you to add a listview webpart to it.
If you need this functionality, a custom SharePoint Framework webpart would be the answer.

Also, it is not possible to switch a modern page to a classic page. If you need the classic page functionalities, webpart or wiki pages should be added (either in SitePages or in Pages library).

**Update**
It appears MS have released List/Library webparts for modern pages just recently.
Rollout will start for first-release tenants, so it might be a while to see it available everywhere though...

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-List-web-part-on-a-modern-page-ef0a1b80-f8b3-443d-b04a-1e76c70b5537

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-Document-Library-web-part-on-a-modern-page-a9dfecc3-2050-4528-9f00-2c5afc5731b0

Answer (score 5):

Customization in modern UI is not possible yet. You can create webpart or wiki pages using SharePoint Designer and then add webparts/views.